# Mysql Index with LIKE and Ordering

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I created a mySql test DB with a single table to make some performance tests.
This table has 4 columns: id, name, email, company.

I filled this table with around 800 000 rows including 10 different companies.

Here are the details of the structure:

[The structure of the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpO5U.png)

I have created many index and i'm trying to figure out why the following query doesn't use the multiple index:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name like 'jo%' order by email
```

I would have expected a very short time but it still takes around 1s.
Any idea?

2nd Question:
This request `SELECT * FROM test WHERE company = 'GB' and name like 'jo%' order by email` takes exactly as much time as the previous. That's not logic since only 10% of the rows have 'GB' as company so it's a lot more restrictive and an index (company,name,email) exists.

Any explanation would help me a lot to optimize it better.

Thanks!

Comment: 1s is not bad time considering there are 800K+ rows, and you are searching within strings, and not looking for exact match.

Comment: You can still analyze and optimize further using `EXPLAIN` statement results.

Comment: I agree but I feel like the index provides enough information to make it a lot faster

Comment: Adding the company restriction is even make it longer...

Comment: `WHERE company = 'GB' name like 'jo%'` is improper syntax; please fix the Question.

Comment: My bad. But my questions are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add full text index

`ALTER TABLE test ADD FULLTEXT INDEX 'MyIndex'(name)`
(this may take a while).

Use full-text search (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).
In your case it will be

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('jo*')`

You can also add full-text indices on other columns, but don't overdo - too many indices also hit performance

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE company = 'GB' and name like 'jo%'
```

needs a 'composite' index:  `INDEX(company, name)` -- in this order.

Because of the "range" (`LIKE 'jo%'`), the index cannot help with the `ORDER BY`.  So, `EXPLAIN` will necessarily show a "filesort".  Don't worry about it.

(Instead of screenshots, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, especially for performance questions.)

(The `FULLTEXT` suggested in another Answer is not likely to be any faster than my Answer *for the sample query*.  It may be faster in other situations.)